# Images in Slideshow isn't displaying in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-animated-slider. It is not displaying the images. Screen is blank.
I have used it before it was working but when I used again, it is not displaying.

This is the code I'm trying:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

import ss1 from '../assets/ss1.jpeg';
import ss2 from '../assets/ss2.jpeg';
import ss3 from '../assets/ss3.jpeg';
import ss4 from '../assets/ss4.jpeg';

import Slider from 'react-animated-slider';
import 'react-animated-slider/build/horizontal.css';



const slides = [
    {
        slideshow: ss1
    },
    {
        slideshow: ss2
    },
    {
        slideshow: ss3
    },
    {
        slideshow: ss4
    }
]

const Careers = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <Slider>
            {slides.map((slide, index) => <div key={index}>
                <img src={slide.slideshow} alt='products'>
            </div>)}
            </Slider>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Careers;
```

Comment: Are your images being imported properly?
Also, can you provide a code sandbox of the above example?

Comment: Yeah images are imported correctly. I don't know about code sandbox. I'm the beginner.

Comment: try giving a height and width to the div that's enclosing your Slider component. I believe that could be the issue.